# GATE Embedded runtime

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, gate

I want to use "GATE" through web. Then I decide to create a SOAP web service in java with help of GATE Embedded.

But for the same document and saved Pipeline, I have a different run-time duration, when GATE Embedded runs as a java web service. 
The same code has a constant run-time when it runs as a Java Application project.

In the web service, the run-time will be increasing after each execution until I get a Timeout error.

Does any one have this kind of experience?

This is my Code:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "GateWS")
public class GateWS {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "gateengineapi")
    public String gateengineapi(@WebParam(name = "PipelineNumber") String PipelineNumber, @WebParam(name = "Documents") String Docs) throws Exception {

        try {

            System.setProperty("gate.home", "C:\\GATE\\");
            System.setProperty("shell.path", "C:\\cygwin2\\bin\\sh.exe");

            Gate.init();

            File GateHome = Gate.getGateHome();
            File FrenchGapp = new File(GateHome, PipelineNumber);
            CorpusController FrenchController;
            FrenchController = (CorpusController) PersistenceManager.loadObjectFromFile(FrenchGapp);

            Corpus corpus = Factory.newCorpus("BatchProcessApp Corpus");
            FrenchController.setCorpus(corpus);

            File docFile = new File(GateHome, Docs);
            Document doc = Factory.newDocument(docFile.toURL(), "utf-8");
            corpus.add(doc);

            FrenchController.execute();

            String docXMLString = null;
            docXMLString = doc.toXml();
            String outputFileName = doc.getName() + ".out.xml";           
            File outputFile = new File(docFile.getParentFile(), outputFileName);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

            OutputStreamWriter out;
            out = new OutputStreamWriter(bos, "utf-8");
            out.write(docXMLString);

            out.close();
            gate.Factory.deleteResource(doc);

            return outputFileName;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return "ERROR: -> " + ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: It could be a memory leak problem. Do you call `gate.Factory.deleteResource(Resource)` for temporary resources (Documents)?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to diagnose the problem - you'll need to show some code.  Are you loading your pipeline afresh for every request or are you loading N copies up-front and pooling them?  Are you properly freeing any temporary resources you have created?  Have you looked through the tutorial documentation on this (module 8 - track 2 Thursday - from [the training course](http://gate.ac.uk/wiki/TrainingCourseJune2013/))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're loading a new instance of the pipeline for every request, but then not freeing it again at the end of the request.  GATE maintains a list internally of every PR/LR/controller that is loaded, so anything you load with `Factory.createResource` or `PersistenceManager.loadObjectFrom...` *must* be freed using `Factory.deleteResource` once it is no longer needed, typically using a try-finally:

```
FrenchController = (CorpusController) PersistenceManager.loadObjectFromFile(FrenchGapp);
try {
  // ...
} finally {
  Factory.deleteResource(FrenchController);
}
```

But...

Rather than loading a new instance of the pipeline every time, I would strongly recommend you explore a more efficient approach to load a smaller number of instances of the pipeline but keep them in memory to serve multiple requests.  There is a fully worked-through example of this technique in the [training materials on the GATE wiki](http://gate.ac.uk/wiki/TrainingCourseJune2013/), in particular module number 8 (track 2 Thursday).

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my time very much.